# Show Rails Console on all the pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-console

When I run into an error on a rails 5.0 app page while on development mode, I receive an error page with the rails `web-console` at the bottom of the page like in the screenshot below. The console seems to be pretty useful for running the methods of that controller in which the error occurred.

[image: Sample console]

Is it possible to enable it on all the pages so I can access it without an error page?

Comment: Why not just use `rails c` in the terminal?

Comment: Personally I haven't used much `rails console` on a terminal. What I am trying to do is execute methods that are in `controllers`, and `models` so I can verify they are working as expected. The reason I am trying to bring it to the page is, when I am on a page that's part of a `controller`, I can then run `methods` that are part of that controller.

Comment: If this is specifically for testing methods on a controller then it would be better to write unit tests. Create the test first with your desired results, then modify the controller until tests pass. It's called Test Driven development (TDD)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the web-console gem [page](https://github.com/rails/web-console), it says you can manually run the console in any page of your application. The docs says the following:

> For example, calling console in a view will display a console in the current page in the context of the view binding.

```
 <% console %>
```

> Calling console in a controller will result in a console in the context of the controller action:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    console
    @post = Post.new
  end
end
```

> The method is defined in Kernel and you can invoke it any application code.
>
> Only one console invocation is allowed once per request. If you happen to have multiple ones, a WebConsole::DoubleRenderError will be raised.

Maybe this will help you call the console on the pages you want it to appear.

Comment: i am getting the following error when I put it inside the controller `undefined local variable or method `console' `

Comment: It's working for me, i tested here. Make sure you're using these versions of the gem:   'webconsole', '>= 3.3.0'  and 'listen', '>=3.0.5'